# Difference between @ModelAttribute before a method and inside the method argument

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller, model

what is the difference between those two @ModelAttribute usage?

```
    public String getMethod(@ModelAttribute UserDetails userDetails){ ... }
```

and

```
@ModelAttribute
public UserDetails getAccount(@RequestParam String user, @RequestParam String emailId)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both cases `@ModelAttribute` will add an attribute to your model (no surprise here). The difference is, that when used on a method, this method will be executed **before** the appropriate `@RequestMapping` method is called. You can use that if you want to add commonly attributes (The list for a drop down choice may be a proper example).

In contrast, when used as a parameter annotation, Spring tries to pass an **already existing** model attribute to your method. In case this doesn't exist, Spring will create a new attribute for you first.

Consult the documentation for details: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.1.7.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-modelattrib-methods

Hope that helps you.